# Is there a SQL statement that will allow me to see results that match from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql

I'm joining two tables (Employee and Matrix) and I'm wondering if there is a statement I can use to only show the names of employees that have a matrix attached to their names after joining the Employee and Matrix tables. I thought of possibly using 'Distinct', but I don't believe that would work as I'm trying to only see employees that have a matrix and this information would be coming from two different tables. 
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is a default join. What is the exact problem with that?

Comment: You talking about join ? theres inner join, that both tables MUST have the same item, and left and right join where only one can have it... but it depends on your problem...

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: If you are interested only in common results of two tables, just use a `INNER JOIN` and the `on` clause use wherever is common on both (ids + maybe something else). This seems to be straight forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `exists` does what you want:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where exists (select 1 from matrix m where m.employee_id = e.employee_id);
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely got me on the right track. This was the final code:SELECT Name
FROM StaffEmployment
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM  capSSMatrix WHERE employeeID = StaffEmployment.employeeID);

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.name
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN matrix m 
ON e.id = m.employee_id
```